# Audio stops when when background video stops

Tags: html, audio, video

I have a little problem. I am using video in mp4 as a background(starts at the beginning). I added a audio file that start playing at beginning too and when video is finished audio stops.

```
<video poster="" id="bgvid" autoplay>
<source src="video/background.mp4" type="video/webm">
<source src="video/background.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<audio autoplay id="backgroundsound" preload="metadata" loop>
  <source src="audio/nuages-dreams.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML5 video tag also add an attribute loop

```
<video id="bgvid" controls loop>
 ...
</video>
```

catching event pause of the video to restart audio :

```
if($("#bgvid").pause()){
   $("#backgroundsound").play();
}
```

But why are you using audio video separately???
2 files medias to load at the start take mutch resources, you need to integrated the audio with video playing in a timeline you can also stopping display video image and play audio with a loop, with only one media file.

Comment: first, i want to use video which when is played stops at the end(and i have got ending frame as a background then) but music still plays.
second, i am using audio and video separately because of the first point.
audio is music (5:32 lenght), video(0:25)

Comment: you can take your "point" integrated the audio inside the video and the video stop in the timeline at 0:25 and the audio still continue during the 5:32 the mp4 lenght = 5:32 you have just use an app tools to do this (adobe premiere, video maker ... ).

Comment: Yep i know what u mean. I just thought it can be done with just html + js. Thanks fot your time. Have a nice day.

Comment: oh you want a js to do this you can catch event pause of the video to restart audio?